# Trying to find out subscription end month notification

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

Hi i have this mysql table

```
id    amount     substart  years   subend

1     200       2012-01-10   1    2013-01-09 
2     250       2012-02-15   2    2014-02-14 
3     100       2012-02-11   1    2013-02-10 
4     260       2012-03-22   3    2015-03-21
```

What i want is that to give notification a month before the end date. The current query is:

```
select  count(subend) as count,curdate() 
from subdur  where  status='active' 
and (date_sub(subend,interval 1 month))>=curdate() 
and (date_sub(subend,interval 1 month))<date_add(curdate(),interval 1 month) 
order by subend;
```

The query is not giving me proper answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the problem with your current query?

Comment: Does your query work? Does it raise any error? Do you have any question?

Comment: It is not giving me proper answer. Like showing me those people who are not just a month far from their date of subend.

Comment: You really need to put more effort into your question. "No proper answer" doesn't actually say anything. If it would give the "proper answer" (whatever that is) you wouldn't have posted a question here. Please show the actual results you are getting and the results you are expecting.

Comment: in query, you have status='active' but there is no status field in table. Please post all the fields of table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this::

```
select  
count(subend) as count,
curdate() 
from subdur  
where  status='active' and 
subend BETWEEN (date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 month)) and curdate() 
order by subend
```

Comment: Oh i got your point. I was getting deep. It was as simple as this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using [`date_diff`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp):

```
select count(subend) as count, curdate() 
from subdur  
where  status='active' 
and date_diff(subend, curdate()) = 30 // >= 30 days or more, = 30 days exact
order by subend
;
```